# How to check if current windows phone device is jailbroken or not?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to develop a application that checks if the current Windows Phone 7 device is jailbroken. How do I detect that?

I think there must be some codes operation after phone jailbroken, but i don't know.
So please point me some ideas or some links is OK! Thanks!

Comment: Ask a particular problem. You are asking solution for the entire problem

Comment: @MaDu_LK not me. Is this better than the original question?

Comment: Jan Dvorak : It seems like ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot detect this just from app running in a sandbox. If you could read registry values or check file consistenty, then it could be possible, but not from regular Windows Phone app.